# different MTU sizes for bond aliases

Tags: linux, networking, mtu, ifconfig

I have a bond interface but I want to change the `MTU` to `1500` only for `bond9:22`

Is this possible?

```
bond9:22  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0E:0C:E4:BE:F9  
          inet addr:10.7.18.58  Bcast:10.7.18.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:1492  Metric:1

bond9:23  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0E:0C:E4:BE:F9  
          inet addr:10.7.18.60  Bcast:10.7.18.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:1492  Metric:1

bond9:24  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0E:0C:E4:BE:F9  
          inet addr:10.7.18.56  Bcast:10.7.18.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:1492  Metric:1
```

Answer (score 1):

What you ask isn't directly possible, as far as I know. Aliased interfaces (eg, bond9:22) aren't really separate interfaces; they are just a way of assigning multiple IP addresses to the same interface. If you change the MTU for bond9:22, you change the MTU for all of the bond9 interface.

I doubt you'll gain much benefit from moving your MTU from 1492 to 1500 anyway.

If you gave some more background on why your MTU is 1492 on your bond9 interface to start with, and why you think you need to change it for a specific IP, you may get more help.